# What are the best ways to write a derived query to Apache SOLR core through python ?

Tags: python, apache, solr

I am using solrpy to access the core and indices in the SOLR server. I wanted to build some some queries. i.e example to find all companies which have an average sales of particular product less than/ more than some amount?

What are the ways in which i can pass such query to solr server using python ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is always the best place to look for examples. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+Python) you can find examples for simple Python and Python with JSON that is more robust.